# c++ win32 listbox and slider create windows application

Tags: c++, listbox

I want to implement a listbox and a slider in my window. 
I use devcpp, not visual studio.

I have looked up for a way to do that and i have found nothing, except theoritical stuff like msdn.microsoft.com provides.

I want an example, the smallest kind of code to implement listbox and slider. 
This is the closer and most helpfull link, but still, it uses visual studio.
Thanks.

Comment: Better use dialog box templates, shortest and easiest way to deal with common controls

Comment: Here are the MSDN examples on [how to build a listbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298365(v=vs.85).aspx) and [how to build a trackbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298370(v=vs.85).aspx) aka the slider. The first control uses the [WC_LISTBOX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491(v=vs.85).aspx#WC_LISTBOX) class and the second one uses the [TRACKBAR_CLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491(v=vs.85).aspx#TRACKBAR_CLASS) class.

Comment: @Ron as i mentioned at my question, msdn.microsoft.com provides halh of the code. this "How to Create a Simple List Box" gives me errors, one of which is the "IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE not defined", obviously becouse its not defined anywhere and i dont know how to define it. 

Also, how do i import the " WC_LISTBOX " and " TRACKBAR_CLASS"? will they solve the error? (i have tried #include and #define, it gives me error)

Comment: @ΧριστιανίδηςΒασίλειος True. If you want to go down the Win32 route I suggest starting with a "Hello World" empty WinAPI form and take it from there.

Comment: @Ron sadly, there are not enough tutorials for win32. everyone use Visual c++ ...  
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I found what i was looking for, it seems that this is the only example code on the entire internet on making listboxes. In order to run it: download and open devc++ (which I use) or any other kind of compiler, open a new Windows application project (otherwise it won't work), erase any default code, paste this code and run it.

And this, is how you help others learn code.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/291276-win32-listbox/

```
#include <Windows.h>


#define IDC_MAIN_BUTTON 101         // Button identifier


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HWND hWndListL;
HWND hWndListR;
HWND hWndButton;


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG Msg;
    HWND hWnd;


    //Settings All Window Class Variables
    WNDCLASSEX WndClsEx;
    WndClsEx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WndClsEx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    WndClsEx.lpfnWndProc = WndProcedure;
    WndClsEx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WndClsEx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WndClsEx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClsEx.hInstance = hInstance;
    WndClsEx.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClsEx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WndClsEx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    WndClsEx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WndClsEx.lpszClassName = "My Window";


    //Register Window Class
    RegisterClassEx(&WndClsEx);


    //Create Window
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "My Window", "Windows Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 200, 640, 480, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);



    SendMessage(hWndListL, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)"one");
    SendMessage(hWndListL, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)"two");



    //Show Window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);


    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }


    return 0;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char buffer[50] = "";


    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            //Create Listbox's
            hWndListL = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "LISTBOX", NULL, WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY, 50, 35, 200, 100, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
            hWndListR = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "LISTBOX", NULL, WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | LBS_NOTIFY, 350, 35, 200, 100, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            //Create Button
            hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "OK", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_DISABLED, 50, 220, 100, 24, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(HIWORD(wParam))
            {
                case LBN_SELCHANGE:
                {
                    //EnableWindow( GetDlgItem( hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON_MAIN ), TRUE );
                    EnableWindow(hWndButton, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
                {
                    //length = SendMessage(hWndListL, LB_GETTEXTLEN, NULL, NULL);
                    SendMessage(hWndListL, LB_GETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buffer);
                    SendMessage(hWndListR, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)buffer);
                    SendMessage(hWndListL, LB_DELETESTRING, NULL, NULL);
                    EnableWindow(hWndButton, false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please watch your language.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Comment: didnt noticed, but i think it automatically deleted the bad word

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code of window with listbox:

```
#include <Windows.h>

/// unique class name
#define CLASS_NAME "MyWinapiClassNameWithUniqeSetOfCharactersThatAreNotMyPassword_50kz5S99g2Q88bTi3ne"

/// unique ID of our listbox command
#define IDC_LISTBOX_ID 123



static LRESULT WINAPI wndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ){
    switch(msg){
        case WM_CREATE:{
            HWND listboxHwnd= CreateWindow( "LISTBOX", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD | LBS_NOTIFY, 10, 10, 200, 100, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_LISTBOX_ID, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 0" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 1" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 2" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 3" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 4" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 5" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 6" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 7" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 8" );
            SendMessage( listboxHwnd, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"List Item 9" );
        }break;
        case WM_COMMAND:{
            switch( LOWORD(wParam) ){
                case IDC_LISTBOX_ID:{
                    switch(HIWORD(wParam)){
                        case LBN_SELCHANGE:{ /// user have selected item in our listbox
                            int id= SendMessage( (HWND)lParam, LB_GETCARETINDEX, 0, 0 ); /// id of seleted item, starting from 0
                            char text[]= "Item 0 selected";
                            text[5] += id; /// thats one way of converting int to string :D
                            MessageBox( NULL, text, "Debug", MB_OK );
                        }break;
                    }
                }break;
            }
        }break;
        case WM_DESTROY:{
            ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        }break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}



int WINAPI WinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd ){
    WNDCLASSEX wc= {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),
        CS_CLASSDC,
        wndProc,
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION ),
        LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW ),
        (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+0),
        NULL,
        CLASS_NAME,
        NULL
    };
    if( !RegisterClassEx(&wc) ){
        MessageBox( NULL, "Fail to register window class.", "Error - Keyboardlord", MB_ICONERROR );
        return -2;
    }

    HWND hwnd= CreateWindow( CLASS_NAME, "App Browser - Keyboardlord", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 250, 150, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
    if( hwnd==NULL ){
        MessageBox( NULL, "Fail to create window", "Error - Keyboardlord", MB_ICONERROR );
        return -3;
    }
    ShowWindow( hwnd, nShowCmd );

    MSG msg;
    while( 0 < GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0) ){
        TranslateMessage( &msg ); 
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    ::DestroyWindow( hwnd );
    ::UnregisterClass( CLASS_NAME, hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```